# Finding closed formula for recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, closed-form

So I'm having some problems finding the closed formula for the following recurrence relation:

$ D_n = D_{n-1} + D_{n-2} $ for $ n >= 2 $ 
where
$ D_0 = 2 $ and $ D_1 = 1 $

I can see that this is the fibonacci sequence but the initial values are throwing me off.

Comment: http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Binet%27s_Formula  and https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler-Binet_Formula

Comment: If you know how to get the closed formula for the fibonacci numbers, the same method works here.  the characteristic polynomial has roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and you want just want constants $A,B$ to get $D_n=A\alpha^n+B\beta^n$.

Comment: To be clear, this is not the fibonacci sequence.  Yes, it's the same recursion, but the initial terms are different.  Your sequence is $\{2,1,3,4,7,11,18,\cdots\}$.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant, I see that its the same relation for the fibonacci sequence but the initial terms make it different.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam No, not at all.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Because the sequences are distinct. For the first values of the D sequence, please refer to lulu's comment above. No member of the Fibonacci sequence is 4, for example.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam $D_3=4$, $n=3$, $n>1$. (Sorry but if your next comments are similar, I might not answer them.)

Comment: @Did I am still waiting for your point of view about the answer i gave.

Answer (score 0):

The chracteristic equation is

$$x^2-x-1=0$$

the roots are

$$a=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
and
$$b=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

thus

$$D_n=Aa^n+Bb^n$$.

with

$$D_0=A+B=2$$
and
$$D_1=Aa+Bb=1$$

which gives

$$A=\frac{1-2b}{a-b}=1$$
and
$$B=\frac{1-2a}{b-a}=1$$

Finally $$D_n=a^n+b^n$$